# Can I use shell_exec or backticks in PHP without having ssh access?

Tags: php, git, shell, ssh, github

I want to use the "Post-Receive URLs" Service Hook on github but I don't have ssh access to my web host. The example I saw on [how to do this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh/).

So I am wondering if I am still able to run shell_exec or [backticks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) in PHP without having ssh access.

Comment: SSH is for connections from your machine to the server. The PHP script is already on the server, so exec() would just fire up a shell on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP would be able to execute the script only if the user which is assigned to the webserver has sufficient permissions to run the script.